# iOS - Side By Side Label Objects in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I am working on creating a very simple dynamic TableViewCell with an image on the far left, a label in the center and a label on the far right like this.

[image: Example]

I currently have the image and center label displaying but I can't seem to figure out how to align the second label object on the far left of the cell.

When I run the app it just displays the image and the center label. 
If anyone has any suggestions on how to go about making a second label object display aligned with the image and first label object it would be greatly appreciated.

TableViewCell:

```
class AttractionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var attractionImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var attractionLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var attractionTime: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

TableViewController:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell =
    self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
        "AttractionTableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        as! AttractionTableViewCell

    let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "blued.jpg")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill


            if (indexPath.section == 0){
        cell.attractionLabel.text = attractionNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.attractionImage.image = UIImage(named: attractionImages[indexPath.row])

    }
    if (indexPath.section == 1){
        cell.attractionLabel.text = attractionNames2[indexPath.row]
        cell.attractionImage.image = UIImage(named: attractionImages2[indexPath.row])

    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: How did you add the first two elements? We need to see some code, look at the constraints you're using.

Comment: Really I just dragged and dropped the image and the label in. For the image I put the width and height equal and then put the view mode to aspect fit. For the label I just dragged and dropped.

Comment: The layout you're showing is that of a regular `UITableViewCell` with style `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`...

Comment: You just dragged and dropped? Didn't added any constraints for the labels?

Comment: No I don't believe there are any constraints. None are shown in the document outline.

Answer (score 2):

Add some Autolayout Constraints.

For the Image:

[image]
[image]

For the middle Label:

[image]

For the right Label:

[image]
[image]

Result should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give the constraints to image view and labels.

You have to give some constraints to the view so they all can be visible on the cell

Give height,width,leading,top constraints to image

Give horizontally center in containers to both uiblables

Give top,bottom ,leading,trailing constraints to lables

Than finally assign text to attractionTime lable in cellForRowAtIndexPath